# Include html in SOAP

Tags: php, html, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I am using a NuSOAP server/client to create posts in my custom made CMS.
I try to send 2 things: a post title (string) and the HTML code of the post. The problem is that the HTML is not received correctly: most of the time only (random) partial.

My code:

**NuSOAP Server**

```
$page_wsdl  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?wsdl';
$server     = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL("SOAP server", $page_wsdl);

$server->register("createPost",
    array("post_title" => "xsd:string", "post_html" => "xsd:string"),
    array("return" => "xsd:string"),
    "$page",
    "$page#createPost",
    "rpc",
    "encoded",
    "Create posts");
```

**NuSOAP Client**

```
$client = new nusoap_client("http://server/soap.php?wsdl=1");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';   

$result = $client->call("createPost", array("post_title" => $title, "post_html" => $html));
print_r($result);

    if ($client->fault) {
            echo $error;
    }
```

What is the correct way to send HTML with SOAP?

Comment: Have you tried `=> htmlspecialchars($html)` or `htmlentities` ?

Comment: @1nflktd  htmlentities() on the client side and html_entity_decode() on the server side is the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htmlentities() on the client side and html_entity_decode() on the server side seems to be the solution.